# Django Class-Based Generic Views Register User

Tags: forms, registration, models, django-class-based-views

Good evening friends.

I'm trying to create an application for easy user registration. Using Django 1.5, my problem is the user is not saved in the database, my code here:

```
#forms.py
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',max_length=30,label='Username')
    email = forms.EmailField(label="E-mail")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label="Password")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label="Repeat Password")

    class Meta:
        models = User
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')

#views.py
from myapp.register.forms import UserCreationForm
class CreateUser(FormView):
     template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'
     success:url = '/'
     form_class = UserCreationForm
    def is_valid(self, form):
        user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                        form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                        form.cleaned_data['password1'])
        #user.save()
        return super(CreateUser, self).form_valid(form)
```

Everytime I try to create a user, they are not saved. What am I doing wrong?

"I am learning a little English, excuse my faults. Thanks"

Comment: Did you mean `form_valid`, not `is_valid`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you do know that you have commented `user.save()`, do you? ;-)

That being said, you're approaching the whole issue in the wrong way. If you're trying to save a model instance, use `CreateView` as the base for your view rather than `FormView`. That way you won't need to write all that code you did, like the `is_valid` method (you also don't need to explicitly set the fields in your form; they will be extrapolated from your model's fields).